# There is a bug with the bounty banner

Tags: bug, design

When a new bounty without a comment appears, the `add a comment` appears half over the grey banner background:

[image]

While not a bad bad bug, it is annoying.

<sup>[First asked on Meta Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11680/there-is-a-bug-with-the-bounty-banner)</sup>

Comment: There really is no need to cross post bug reports. Really. In particular if they only effect a single site.

Comment: @Oded I expected it would also be on here, and I just checked and it's also on [SO]. Should I delete this? https://imgur.com/NpPnpRu

Comment: @Stijn yes, but this is only the add a comment button...